# Partition of the 3d space with circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, integer-partitions

Does it exist a partition of the 3d space with circles of positive radium?

I know the answer is no for a plane, but I can not transpose my demonstration to the space and I have no clue on how to do it. Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28647/is-it-possible-to-partition-mathbb-r3-into-unit-circles

Comment: @DanielRust Thanks a lot! I think the question can be closed